# Can I have two angular.module calls to the same ng-app in two different files for same controller?

Tags: angularjs

Hi I have created two angulerjs files for same ng-app example.

admin.js

```
 var app = angular.module('arcadminmodule', ['ngTable', 'ui-notification']);
    app.controller('ArcAdminController', ['$http', '$scope', '$filter', '$interval', 'ngTableParams', 'Notification', function($http, $scope, $filter, $interval, ngTableParams, Notification) {});
```

admin1.js

```
var app = angular.module('arcadminmodule');
    app.controller('ArcAdminController', ['$http', '$scope', '$filter', '$interval', 'ngTableParams', 'Notification', function($http, $scope, $filter, $interval, ngTableParams, Notification) {});
```

But its overriding admin.js from admin1.js

please help me out....

Comment: Just i want separate the code from admin.js from admin1.js.

Comment: Of course it overwriting: you're defining the same controller twice. Choose a different name for your controllers.

Comment: How can I achieve **what**? What do you want to do?

Comment: can I use same controller reference in anotherjs also ?

Answer (score 0):

In admin1.js when you write:

```
var app = angular.module('arcadminmodule');
```

you are not creating a new module. You are trying to get an existing module named 'arcadminmodule'.. If you want to create a new module, you will have to write something like this:

```
  var app = angular.module('arcadminmodule',[]); // add your depencencies...
```

Now, In your case, in admin.js you are creating your module and admin1,js you are making use of the same module. In angular you cannot have two controllers with the same name. Controllers are for (from the docs):

1. Set up the initial state of the $scope object.
2. Add behavior to the $scope object.

So If you need are trying to apply some roles or some business logic, It need to go into one controller. **Make sure your controller contain only the business logic needed for a single view.**

Comment: can i use same controller in another js also?

Comment: What do you mean use the same controller in another js? Are you trying to access (call) some methods or properties ( get /set ) values?

Comment: My requirement is to just externalize the code from admin.js to admin1.js with same controller and same module.

Comment: So you have different views for admin and admin1? Then why don't you use two different controllers?

Comment: If use like that i am getting exception as Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'PresourceThresholdController' is not a function, got undefined

Answer (score 0):

I think its no need for use the same controller in two places.But you can use services in  places.If you need to do some think different from the ArcAdminController,use this structure.

Services
-service1.js

```js
(function (angular) {
    angular.module('marineControllers').service('boatService', function (ajaxService) {
      }
                                                )
```

-service2.js
-module..js

```js
var artistControllers = angular.module('marineControllers',['ngAnimate']);
```

Controllers
-controller1

```js
(function (angular) {
    angular.module('marineControllers').controller("BoatController", ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams',
        'dashboardService', '$filter', 'loginService', '$location', 'boatService', 'autocompleteFactory', 'utilityFactory',
        function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, dashboardService, $filter, loginService, $location, boatService, autocompleteFactory, utilityFactory) {
                      
          
          function loadAllFishingBoat() {
                $scope.boatsTable.length = 0;
                if (!$scope.$$phase)
                    $scope.$apply();
                boatService.getAllBoatAndDevice().then(function (data) {
                    $scope.boatsTable = data;
                    if (!$scope.$$phase)
                        $scope.$apply();
                });
            };

          
                  }]);
})(angular);
```

-controller2

```js
(function (angular) {
angular.module('marineControllers').controller("DeviceController", ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams',
    'dashboardService', '$filter', 'loginService', '$location', 'deviceService', 'autocompleteFactory', 'utilityFactory','commonDataService',
    function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, dashboardService, $filter, loginService, $location, deviceService, autocompleteFactory, utilityFactory,commonDataService) {

        function loadAllFishingBoat() {
            $scope.boatsTable.length = 0;
            if (!$scope.$$phase)
                $scope.$apply();
            boatService.getAllBoatAndDevice().then(function (data) {
                $scope.boatsTable = data;
                if (!$scope.$$phase)
                    $scope.$apply();
            });
        };


    }]);

})(angular);
```

I have been use many services in both controllers,still they are different logics.